# how to select a column from one table according to another table column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have 2 tables 'users' and 'criteria'.

*users*

```
------------------------------
username, age, height, country
------------------------------
```

*criteria*

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
username, age_from, age_to, height_from, height_to, country
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to write a query that 'users' age between 'age_from' and 'age_to'

AND

'users' 'height' between 'height_from' and 'height_to'

Comment: And... what have you tried??? Have you even google it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables:

```
SELECT  u.*
FROM Users          AS u
INNER JOIN criteria AS c  ON u.hiehgt BETWEEN c.height_from 
                                          AND c.height_to
                         AND u.age    BETWEEN c.age_from 
                                          AND c.age_to;
```

You might also need to use `OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` to get those unmatched rows, see this for more information:

- [**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @echo_me - Thanks, nice to see you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN criteria c
WHERE u.age    BETWEEN c.age_from AND c.age_to 
  AND u.height BETWEEN c.height_from AND c.height_to;
```

Comment: This can't work - I don't see the 'criteria' table in your answer.

Comment: Friends thaks for your commensts at last i found a way myself